# Resizing images to a fixed size

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I need to resize images with multiple dimensions to same size . Those are profile images and I can crop width or height of image if needed to make aspect ratio similar . Also  I need to add watermark to image . Suggest any library which is good for image manipulation.

Thanks

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı Well, I know its possible , I was asking for suggestions of a C# library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is very good, has bindings to most language and is available for most operating systems - it is also free.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short list I can remember:

http://www.graphicsmill.com/

http://imageresizing.net/

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/

http://www.coreoptical.com/

http://www.leadtools.com/

Actually your task is pretty simple so I guess most of SDKs will easily handle that. And if you don’t need any specials about .net integration, Image Magick should be good enough.